# I created signup-login app. Sign up is working fine but as I click on login button, my app is getting terminated

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using searchPass() method which is defined in my code below, to check username and password and I think that error is in this searchPass() method only. When I ran my project in debug mode, I found that error is in line "Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);". Please help me to debug this code.

This is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.admin.loginregistraionusingsqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts(id integer primary key,name text,email text,uname text,password text)";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void insertContact(Contact c)
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from contacts";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, c.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_UNAME, c.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, c.getPassword());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        //cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String uname)
    {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select uname, password from"+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String a, b; // a for username and b for password
        b = "not found";
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);

                if(a.equals(uname))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat..

Answer (score 1):

There's no space after 'from'.

```
String query = "select uname, password from"+TABLE_NAME;
```

It should be

```
String query = "select uname, password from "+TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Nice observation.. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much Jyotman. You made a very good observation. I was not able to figure it out for the last 4 day. Now my app is running successfully. Thanks...